# HTML5 unsupported attributes work in Live Server on VScode

Tags: html, frontend

as Mentioned in the title. I'm wondering If I can use this "supposedly" unsupported attributes in HTML5? If not, than what's going on?
I started relearning HTML recently and noticed this. I'm a beginner.
Example Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table border="2px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Red
            </td>
            <td>
                Blue
            </td>
            <td>
                Green
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I've noticed syntax highlighting using One Dark Pro theme show's this unsupported attributes as white. Hope this Helps and thx!

Comment: So, what do you really want?

Comment: Sorry , forgot to mention.
I'm just looking for an explanation on the matter. Are there actually not any "illegal" attributes in HTML5? Or am I missing Something?
This is my declaration by the way: <!DOCTYPE html>.
Also I'll edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "work in LiveServer"? That it does not throw an error? Yes, in principle you can use any tagname or attribute you want in HTML. But the browser may not be able to interpret it and possibly just ignores it.

Comment: Nope, I mean it just works. The table and his nested elements show a border. Of course I tried removing the border attribute and the border disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border` is not unsupported in most browsers. It's *obsolete and deprecated*. Even though it was removed from the HTML spec before HTML5, it may still work in some browsers. It is however, invalid.

If you want to check your HTML doesn't have any errors, use [The W3C Vlaidator](https://validator.w3.org/).